Show all logs references of a specific remote in Magit
I want the same result as magit-log-all (l a shortcut) but restricted to a single remote (origin in my case).
Is there any way to do that ?

It's not really a normal shortcut, but you can pass git-log's --remotes flag to magit-log-other instead of a real ref.
So the shortcut looks something like l o --remotes=origin RET (of course, there's no completion for this).
